# change browser href in combobox option

Tags: php, html, css, sql, google-chrome

I try to make a list of data from a table in a database. I do this with an select option, because the user is only allowed to choose one.

I do it on this way:

```
<select name="test">
 <option value="line1">Line1</option>
 <option value="line2">Line2</option>
 <option value="other.php" onClick="window.location.href='other.php'">
 Other
</option>
</select>
```

This works in IE and Firefox, but not in Google Chrome.

It's not an option to put the `onClick` in the `<select>`-tag, because they don't have a href and I need their values to get the primary key and store something in the table.

I hope you can help me.

**UPDATE:** this is the solution for my case, solved by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry)

```
<select name="test" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value.indexOf('.php')!=-1 && 
         (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
 <option value="line1">Line1</option>
 <option value="line2">Line2</option>
 <option value="other.php">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: normally, there is no click event on a `<option>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code and check if it solves your problem. You needn't have the `href` values in the `select` tag for this to work. The `href` can be in your option's `value` tag.

**UPDATE**: The below code would do the redirect only if the `value` of the selected option tag has `.php` in it. For the first two options, no action will be taken.

```
<select name="test" 
    onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value.indexOf('.php')!=-1 && 
             (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="line1">Line1</option>
    <option value="line2">Line2</option>
    <option value="other.php">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works for the link, but when you've click on Line2, it will return Line1 and in the url ?line2

Comment: @Kenny so only the third option needs a link and not others, is my understanding correct? check the update to the answer for a different version and let me know if it still doesnt solve your case.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't valid HTML. it should at least be:

```
<option value="other.php" onClick="window.location.href='other.php'">
```

Comment: Excuse me, I typed to fast, I did it in your way :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select name="test" 
onchange="var val = this.value; 
  if (val.indexOf('other.php')!=-1) window.location=loc">
 <option value="line1">Line1</option>
 <option value="line2">Line2</option>
 <option value="other.php">Other</option>
</select>
```